# Discontinuity in the electric potential for a uniform coil rotating in the magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Consider a uniform coil rotating in a uniform magnetic field. By electromagnetic induction, there will be induced current around the coil. Thus, there will be a potential difference across it. As the coil is uniform, the electric potential will descend at a constant rate as one moves around the coil, which inevitably leads to a discontinuity in the electric potential for every full cycle around the coil (the potential can't be multivalued). How can one make sense of this?

Also, I reckon this is quite similar to the fact that the line integral of a vector field around the origin is nonzero if the field is conservative everywhere but nondefined at the origin. I wonder if there is a connection between the two.

Comment: Also, besides what I have mentioned in my answer. Why did you assume it was an electric force causing the EMF? the emf is caused by the magnetic lorentz force

Comment: how are the coil and its rotation axis oriented wrt the magnetic field?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the potential graph would not have a discontinuity, For the simple reason that potential cannot be defined since the line integral of the force is PATH DEPENDANT. Your intuition about the potential graph is wrong simply because potential doesn't make sense. The potential at the "start" of your path, wouldn't be higher then the "end" of your path, because the start and end of the path is arbitrary, it is a closed loop, the field is non Conservative so you cannot assign a potential to a point in space.
The closest thing that you'd get to this, is a battery and a wire. The potential decreases as you go from the positive to the negative terminal along the wire, and then the field direction FLIPS inside the battery. Even in this scenario, the potential is continuous.

The electric potential in electrostatics is always continuous, apart from at the origin of a point charge.

P.s the closed line integral of a Conservative vector field is always 0

Answer (score -1):

As the coil is a real object, the domain of integration for the angle in the problem is [image: [0,2\pi)]). You need to match the maths with reality.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer?  I'm not sure what you mean by it.